# How can I point a subdomain to a specific bundle?

Tags: php, symfony, routes, virtualhost, symfony-routing

How can I point a subdomain to a specific bundle. I have this `vhost`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName subdomain1.mysite.dev
    ServerAlias subdomain2.mysite.dev

    DocumentRoot /mysite/web
    <Directory /mysite/web>
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

This `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1       subdomain1.mysite.dev subdomain2.mysite.dev
```

And this `app/routing.yml`:

```
subdomain1:
    resource: "@ProjectSubdomain1Bundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    host: subdomain1.mysite.dev

subdomain2:
    resource: "@ProjectSubdomain2Bundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    host: subdomain2.mysite.dev
```

This way both subdomains goes to `Subdomain1Bundle`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I'm shamed. I just needed to clean the production cache:

```
app/console --env=prod cache:clear
```

Because I was developing before with `server:run` mode. Anyway I will keep the above example because it works perfectly.